# Generate Alpha Numeric Sequence in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle11g

I want to generate a string sequence in c#.And this sequence starts with 1 and ends on ZZ. **for e.g.:**-

```
1-99
A0-A9
AA-AZ
B0-B9
BA-BZ
.....
....
Z0-Z9
ZA-ZZ
```

So this is a sequence that i wants to generate and the the length not more then 2 characters means the end of sequence is ZZ.

So Please help me out and if possible can we also do it in oracle.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards
Anil

Comment: what about 1a,1b... 2g,2h etc.. is that included or not?

Comment: No it's not and the sequence is clear that it starts from 1-99,A1-A9 then AA-AZ till ZA-ZZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a string like "123456789101112...99A0A1...ZZ", right?

This should fit:

```
string sequenceStr = "";
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    sequenceStr += i.ToString();

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 36; j++)
    {
        sequenceStr += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { (byte)(i + 65) }); // A=65, B=66, ...
        if (j < 10)
        {
            sequenceStr += j.ToString();
        }
        if (j > 9)
        {
            sequenceStr += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { (byte)(j + 55) }); 
        }
    }
}
```